# Where do I find error logs for Exchange 2010 Web Services

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, web-services

Probably a simple question, but I really can't find the answer on Google.

We are creating an application that talks to Exchange Web Services. We have some messages working, but certain other requests just return a 500 error.

I have been unable to find anything that explains where I might be able to find more details of the errors.

Exchange appears to log (at least some things) to the Windows Event Log but there is nothing in there to do with these 500 errors we are getting.

Are we looking in the wrong place or do we need to configure Exchange in some way to log the relevant information?

Comment: Do your IIS logs provide any further information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs are in the IIS logs as @tnolan said, but there's often nothing useful there.

To get the error messages you need to turn on detailed error pages for remote connections in IIS Manager.

Go on the site in the manager, select Error Pages then Edit Feature Settings, Detailed Errors.

Hopefully they'll be of a bit more use.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't EWS stored in the IIS logs?  C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 would be the default, but you would want to start up inetmgr to check where the log files are stored for the exchange site in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Try here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Logging\Ews
```